# A vector in one class being used by another class is failing to store items

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a Graph class which has populates its Population vector of type Person (another class) with information from a file. The person class has a Conns vector which stores all the people the person has come into contact with. The Graph class also populates the Conns vector in each Person in the Population vector. **The code does not give me any errors**, but when I print what is in the Conns vector of the people in the Population Vector **I get nothing**.

This is the vector in the Person class and how it is adds to it

```
//Person.h
private:
   std::vector<Person> conns;
public:
   void addConn(Person person);
   void printConns();

//Person.cpp
void Person::addConn(Person person){
    conns.push_back(person);
}

void Person::printConns(){
    if (conns.empty()){
        cout << "There are no connections for " << name << endl;
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < conns.size(); i++){
            cout << getName() << "-------" << conns[i].getName() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how Graph class and how its populates the Conns vector in each Person

```
//Graph.h
private:
   std::vector<Person> population;
   void populate(std::string fileName);
   void addConnections(std::string fileName);
public:
   Graph(std::string pop_file, std::string conn_file);
   Person findPerson(std::string name);

//Graph.cpp
Graph::Graph(string pop_file, string conn_file){
   populate(pop_file); //Add people to the population vector
   addConnections(conn_file); //Add the connections to the respective people
}

void Graph::addConnections(string fileName){
//The file is read and a while loop is used to retrieve info[0] and //info[1] from the file

   Person contacter = findPerson(info[0]); //Get the person object of the "contacter"
   Person contactee = findPerson(info[1]); //Get the person object of the "contactee"

   //Add the connection to the person
   contacter.addConn(contactee)

}

//This method is used to retrieve a person object from a person vector
Person Graph::findPerson(string name){
    if (population.empty()){
        cout << "Empty vector does not contain any one!" << endl;
    }else{
        for (int i =0; i < population.size(); i++){

            //Check if the names are equal and return the person object
            if (population[i].getName().compare(name) == 0){
                return population[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***NB: I get the correct information when I print out Contacter and Contactee in addConnections() before and after the addition into the Conns vector***

I print the population and conns vector from the graph in the main file but this is the result I get

```
int main(){
   Graph graph(pop_file, conn_file);
   graph.printPop(); //Prints the info of the people in the population vector
   for (int i = 0; i < graph.getPop().size(); i ++){
       graph.getPop()[i].printConns();  //getPop() returns the population vector
      }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:
Name: Adrienne 
Age: 12 
Spread Probability: 0.32

Name: Robert 
Age: 85 
Spread Probability: 0.1

Name: Gary 
Age: 47 
Spread Probability: 0.45

There are no connections for Adrienne

There are no connections for Robert

There are no connections for Gary

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. your `Graph.h` starts with `private:`, same with `Person.h`, while other things are probably not related to the problem and maybe could be removed

Comment: Is it a good idea to copy a person (`addConn()` has a value parameter) into the `conns` vector of another `Person`? Now, you have a Person with a connection which might be in another Person's connection vector without this connection. Thus, the same person might be considered as different. I believe I would design this with Persons and Connections in separate classes / variables.

Comment: I often saw graphs with nodes and edges in two different containers. In your case, Persons are the nodes and connections are the edges. And, I would consider whether the connections should be bi-directional. (Though, if A knows B then it doesn't necessarily mean B knows A as well. - It's tricky.) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Person contacter = findPerson(info[0]); //Get the person object of the "contacter"
Person contactee = findPerson(info[1]); //Get the person object of the "contactee"

//Add the connection to the person
contacter.addConn(contactee)
```

`contacter` is a local copy of the `Person` in `population`, not the same object. So it adds a contact, then gets destroyed at the `}`, while the element of `population` has not changed at all.

Also, your `findPerson` is missing a `return` statement if the person is not found. Make sure to enable and read compiler warnings, because they should report this serious problem.

You need a pointer or reference to use an object from a container or otherwise stored elsewhere. Since `findPerson` might not actually find a `Person`, a pointer which might be null is probably easiest.

```
//This method is used to retrieve a person object from a person vector
Person* Graph::findPerson(string name){
    if (population.empty()){
        cout << "Empty vector does not contain any one!" << endl;
    }else{
        for (int i =0; i < population.size(); i++){

            //Check if the names are equal and return the person object
            if (population[i].getName().compare(name) == 0){
                return &population[i]; // *** NOTE THE &
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr; // *** ADDED
}

void Graph::addConnections(string fileName){
//The file is read and a while loop is used to retrieve info[0] and //info[1] from the file

   Person* contacter = findPerson(info[0]); //Get the person object of the "contacter"
   Person* contactee = findPerson(info[1]); //Get the person object of the "contactee"

   if (contacter && contactee) {
       //Add the connection to the person
       contacter->addConn(*contactee)
   }
}
```